# Is it normal for an acoustic guitar advertised as a solid top to have runout?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

The guitar I bought is claimed to be a solid top and it looks like the right guitar on the [link](http://www.rod-neep.com/rod/instruments/odds/runout1.jpg).

Comment: Runout is not quite exactly 90° grain. It bugs the heck out of some people & doesn't bother others. Until it gets a long way out, it's usually merely cosmetic. Book matching [halving & reversing] is why you see dark one side & light the other, flip the guitar 180° & the effect will reverse.

Answer (score 3):

There’s nothing wrong with there being runout on a book matched solid wood guitar top. Or at least nothing about it that suggests it’s not actually book matched solid wood.

Since some don’t like visible runout, it’s almost more authentic because why would you add fake runout to a top that is not book matched solid wood?